# How to add a custom section / page with an embedded app in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, storefront, shopify-api-node

For a client i want to integrate a new way of renting products in Shopify which they pick right up after ordering from a pickup point. This new way is a service which can be interacted with via an API. After ordering, a code is provided which can be used to open a locker somewhere. In the shop, on a custom page or some sort of reusable block i want have a custom HTML form which can interact with this API. The customer can then choose the product, the available pickup-point, pay for his/her order and receive the code for pickup. Is this possible?

I have done research but could not find this type of customizing.

I have built some test-apps but it seems these can only be embedded in the admin and not in the storefront itself (please correct me if i am wrong). I can interact with the storefront-api so that's a plus allright.

The ideal way would be for me to develop a React/Vue app which can be added to a page for walking trough this process described above.

Anyway, is it possible one way or another?

Thanks in advance for thinking with me on this one!

Comment: Yes, it is 100% possible to do what you want to do. Unfortunately, this is not the place to ask for general basic howto help. When you have a specific technical question, then this is the perfect place to ask it.

Comment: True. Did manage to do it by the way ;)